# How to connect Service bus queue in a logic app workflow using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-cli, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a scenario where in i want to create a CLI Command so that i can create a Logic app with `"When_a_message_is_received_in_a_queue_(auto-complete)"` but not sure how to pass the connection string to connect to the Queue which i created earlier. Below is the command which am using currently. Testdefinition Json has the old resource group which i created from Azure Console but not working with the new resource group and this json doesn't have connectionstring anywhere which i used earlier in the console. Any help is appreciated

```
# Creat logic app and workflow
az logic workflow create --resource-group "demoss-rg1" --location "westeurope" --name "demo-la" --definition "C:\testDefinition.json"
```

Comment: Its bit confusing query. But as per my understanding, you don't need to pass the connection string of the queue to Logic App. you have to crete the Logic app connector & need to pass the connection string to that & the connector should be configured to Logic app.

Comment: @lokanathdas Thanks for the reply. is it possible to create logic app connector via Azure CLI. Any link available?

Comment: https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd , it will be something like this. your CLI command is fine, it's like a script executor. all required details need to be in the "C:\testDefinition.json" file. That is your ARM template

Answer (score 0):

Like @Lokanath das mentioned you don't pass the connection string but you need to create it and then add the connection string to it.

> is it possible to create a logic app connector via Azure CLI. Any link available?

One of the workarounds that you can try is to use the template.json and parameter.json files for creating a logic app as per your requirement using the below command.

```
az deployment group create --name ExampleDeployment --resource-group ExampleGroup --template-file storage.json --parameters parameters.json
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Create parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files#deploy-template-with-parameter-file)
2. [Workflow Definition Language schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#workflow-definition-structure)